# Flatness, "Continuously varying fibers", and bordism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, cobordism, flatness

It is commonly said that a flat map of schemes $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is like a map with "continuously varying fibers". We see a hint at this in the result that $\text{dim} X_y$ is constant when $f$ is faithfully flat and $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible. However, defining the full intuition formally is difficult.

Someone suggested to me that the geometric picture for this is much like cobordism. Continuously varying fibers seems much like how a smooth map of manifolds $f : M \rightarrow I$ (with $I$ the unit interval) has fibers $ f^{-1}(\{ x \})$ that "vary continuously" with $x$.

[image: Cobordism[![][1]]

With this in mind, I am trying to develop geometric intuition for flatness using manifolds.

For my question, let $F : X \rightarrow I$ be a map of $C^{\infty}$-schemes, where $I$ is the unit interval. How might we express that $F_U : \mathcal{O}_I(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(F^{-1}(U))$ is a flat map in terms of boordisms? Perhaps boordisms correspond to flat maps of $C^{\infty}$-schemes $F : X \rightarrow I$?

A harder question is how to develop geometric way of expressing that a map $F : X \rightarrow Y$ of $C^{\infty}$-schemes is flat. I am also quite interested in this if you have insights to share.

---

Note: I tagged this under algebraic geometry as well since I think algebraic geometers may be interested in how this relates to flat morphisms of schemes. Ultimately my goal is to understand flatness of maps of schemes.